# Serve single HTTP request without blocking

Tags: python, linux, http, networking

I am writing a script which involves opening an HTTP server and serving a single file. However, the request for this file is also instigated from further down the script. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```py
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8000), Handler)
Thread(target=httpd.handle_request).start()
```

This works to handle a single request, but also creates some issues with keyboard input. What is the most efficient, non-blocking way to serve a single HTTP request? Ideally the server would close and release the port upon the completion of the request.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request from your script to the same script?  What on earth is the purpose of that?  Just pass the information in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can try many workarounds but `flask` is the way to go. It is not the simplest or fastest solution but it is the most relieble one.

Example for serving a single file with flask:

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/file-downloads/')
def file_downloads():
    try:
        return render_template('downloads.html')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

app.run()
```

for a non blocking solution you can do this instead of `app.run()`:

```
Thread(target=app.run).start()
```

But I don't recommend running the flask app in a thread because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: Flask seems a bit heavy for the purpose. It's a fast running script, and this seems to add a lot of overhead for serving a single file.

Comment: Yes you are absulately right, but as I mentioned in the answer, it is not the fastest (or in this case lightest) solution, but it is still reliable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [handle_request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.handle_request) method to handle a single request, and if you use the server inside a [with statement](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) then Python will close the server and release the port when the statement exits. (Alternatively, you can use the [server_close](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.server_close) method to close the server and release the port if you want, but the with statement provides better error handling.) If you do all of that in a separate thread, you should get the behaviour you are looking for.

Using Python 3:

```
from threading import Thread
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

def serve_one_request():
    with HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) as server:
        server.handle_request()
    
thread = Thread(target=serve_one_request)
thread.start()
# Do other work
thread.join()
```

I'm not sure if this will fix the issues with keyboard input you mentioned. If you elaborate on that some more I will take a look.